# If $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)g(x)=0$, then $\lim f(x)=0$ or $\lim g(x)=0$ at $x_0$. Is my counterexample fine?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

True/false:

If $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)g(x)=0$, then $\lim f(x)=0$ or $\lim g(x)=0$ at $x_0$.

I think the claim is not true!

Can we define functions $f, g$ as follows:
$$
f = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if $x \in Q$}\\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\
g = \begin{cases}
      0 & \text{if $x \in Q$}\\
      1 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
So both $f, g$ diverge as Dirichlet function, but $fg=0$ which converges to $0$ at any $x_0$.

Is this counterexample right?
Thanks!

Comment: 100% right!! Well done!

Comment: Yes, it is a correct counterexample.

Comment: Really neat counterexample as well, nicely done!

Comment: The counterexample is right, but your writing is a little messy. For example, "$fg=0$ which converges to $0$", converges to $0$ when what tends to what? what is $x_0$? You're supposed to give $f$, $g$ and $x_0$

Comment: I meant that fg is the 'zero function' it is a constant function and so it converge to itself,  I already defined f and g, cannot one takes $x_0$ to be any poiny I want like $x_0=0$? @jjagmath

Comment: @Bestmat Yes $fg$ is the zero function. But saying a function converges doesn't makes sense. Does $\sin$ converges? One should say "the **limit** of a function converges **as the variable tends to ...**". And yes, you could take $x_0$ to be any point, but you should mention that.

Answer (score 2):

Although the posted counter example is good, the original formula being given is still valid.  The difficulty is that the posted formula includes the premise that for both of the functions $f$ and $g$, the limit as $x\to x_0$ must exist.

This explains why the counter example is possible.  In the counter example, the premise that both limits exist is violated.

Comment: Which counte example do you suggest?

Comment: @Bestmat  If the premises of the original theorem are met, that $~\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)~$ exists (implying a finite limit), and that $~\displaystyle \lim_{x\to x_0} g(x)~$ exists, then no counter example is possible.  In that case, the limit of the product of the two functions **must** equal the product of the limits of the two functions.